# Thymeleaf or JSP: which is better with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot, thymeleaf

- Is Thymeleaf better with Spring Boot than JSP?
- How about their *performance*?
- Is there any suggestion for alternate UI framework to work with
  Spring Boot?

Comment: Thymeleaf is always better as it's a spring solution, then they make it a better integration with boot, I am using thymeleaf since years with spring boot and works perfect

Comment: JSP is a dated technology.  Thymeleaf can run on server and client.  I would prefer Thymeleaf or FreeMarker over JSP.

Comment: @cralfaro Thanks for helping. is there any performance issues with Thymeleaf  i saw some blog posts that Thymeleaf  is running slow than others is that true or what?

Comment: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thvsjsp.html

Comment: @praneeth if you use the latest thymeleaf version 3.x the speed is much better and also the readibility and other extra functionality rather JSP deserve the MS difference

Comment: @cralfaro Thanks and appreciate your help i will use the thymeleaf version 3.x with my boot application

Comment: @praneeth good choice :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a matter of user choice. Thymeleaf and JSP are both *viewing templates* with both having edge over the other.

I like JSP for its particular simplicity of usage but on the other hand, Thymeleaf resolution for internationalization *i18n* is to say the least great, amongst extra expression it has like the way it handles the context path automatically.

Thymeleaf is a bit complicated when resolving variables from model unlike in JSP, where you can easily concatenate literals with variable expressions. Furthermore, JSP can easily resolve URLs from *variable expression* directly from database whereas Thymeleaf has difficulty achieving that.

I have used JSP for a while now, likewise Thymeleaf and I must say, both are great technologies. If your application is simple and would not allow for internationalization support, I would say JSP is not a bad choice. But Thymeleaf is better for a robust application that requires internalization amongst others. The idea of tagging JSP "old technology" is not entirely true at all.

So, my conclusion is it's a matter of choice.